# Are you supposed to remove the sheets from oil painting pads?

Tags: paper, oil-paint

I had my first go at oil painting on the weekend.I was given some basic beginner supplies for Christmas. This included a *"Belle Vous"* Oil Painting Pad with 12 sheets. I thoroughly enjoyed my first go using a wet-on-wet style but was taken by surprise how long it can take oils to dry properly.

This may seem like a non-question to some people, but when using a pad like this, would you pull a sheet out from the pad before painting so you can use more before it's dried? Would you have multiple pads and rotate them whilst another is drying so you can have a sort of "art book" of completed pictures at the end? Or am I greatly over worrying about the fragility of oil paint and leaving it for a day will make it "dry enough" to just flip over to another sheet? Or perhaps am I supposed to do something so it dries in better time?

Comment: As a beginner, please be aware that oil paints and rags can combust if not stored properly. See this [related question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/8018/6316) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You paint on only one sheet at a time, removing it and placing it on a table, easel, or other surface of your choice. You can use a hard or stiff backboard if needed. It does take a long time for oils to dry.